# Laravel authorization using middleware

Tags: laravel, authorization, laravel-5.3

I have following tables:

**Role Table**

1. ID
2. Title

**Permission Table**

1. ID
2. Title
3. Role_id
4. Permissions ( like : {test:"create","edit","update","delete"} )

Now after logging in how can I check through middleware whether that specific user has above permissions, whether he can create/edit/update/delete.

I don't want to specify the permissions or role name in routes.

```
Route::group(['permission'=>'create-user'] ...
```

Instead want to check with the help of middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'authorization'] ...
```

So that I don't have to specify individual permissions in route each time new role and permissions to those role has been added.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a middleware and in the handle method of that middleware just check for the permissions

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $records = DB::table('role_table')
                  ->join('permissions_table', 'role_table.ID', '=', 'permissions_table.Role_id')
                  ->select('permissions_table.Permissions')
                  ->first();

    if (count($records) > 0) {

        $permisssions = json_decode($records->Permissions, true);

        if (in_array("create", $permissions['test'])) {
           // has permission to create
           // redirect to the authorized page 
        }
        ...

    } else {
       return redirect('to access denied page');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

add the middleware to `App\Http\Kernel.php` `$routeMiddleware` array

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 'authorization' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthorizationMiddleware::class
];
```